# How to fetch information from "WHMCS user session" in third party code?

Tags: php, session, whmcs

How can i detect whether user is logged in or not into whmcs and use it in a third-party PHP code? I noticed there is a method ([AutoAuth](http://docs.whmcs.com/AutoAuth)) for loggin in users. But i also want to know whether the user is already logged in or not. is there any API or method for this ?

Answer (score 1):

WHMCS utilizes standard php sessions to check whether a user in logged in or not. Session id is usually saved in *PHPSESSID* cookie. Do know, that WHMCS allows a client to have more than one active session (f.e. concurrent logins from different hosts, browsers etc.)

To know whether a user is logged in you have to know if he has at least one active session.  I know nothing about the data WHMCS holds in the session. I don't know if WHMCS encrypts this data or not as well. If not, you have to walk though all sessions and determine if it is active and belongs to the client. Usually sessions are stored as serialized arrays in some *tmp* folder. Actually, the task can be quite complex.

Probably you want to know something different about a client, but I know nothing about the context.

Comment: thank Maksym. actually i want to have a simple login panel that is identical in whmcs and third-party code. and this third-party code will be my hosting company's home page. so basically i need user's id to fetch everything from DB and recreate whmcs's Navigation menu. but i was hoping there would be a simpler way.

Comment: @NOjAN Usually the problem is solved vise versa: they create a custom WHMCS theme which duplicates main site menu; WHMCS instance is placed under the */billing/* URI; a link "Client's area" is places at the homepage. See for example surfsafevpn.com, myprivateproxy.com, squidproxies.com